# How can I un-write protect file made by tee?

Tags: shell-script, tee

I have a small program and I want to ensure that it works on both write protected files and un-write protected files. So, instead of using `echo $text > $file` or `echo $text >> $file`, I am instead forced to use `echo $text | sudo tee $file` and `echo $text | sudo tee --append $file`, respectively. When I use `sudo tee`, even if I change the permissions, whenever I use `rm` on the file, it prompts me like so:

```
$ ls
someFile writeProtectedFile
$ rm someFile
$ ls
writeProtectedFile
$ rm writeProtectedFile
rm remove write-protected regular file 'writeProtectedFile'? yes
$ ls
```

I then poked around on the web, looking for possible solutions to my dilemma. There were only two out there that I could find: incorrect permissions, or a changed set of permissions. I knew the permissions case to be incorrect, because I could easily change the permissions by running `sudo chmod xxx filename`, which would result in a successful permissions change. I assumed then that there was a problem with the file attributes, so I ran `lsattr` on the file and it would output `-------------e--`, same as every other file in the directory.

#### Update

The reason I was using `tee` was to echo text to write protected files, but as a side effect it also write protected regular files... My goal was to, in effect, do something like `sudo echo "whatever" >> /etc/someFile`, which does not work, so I found a solution in `echo "whatever" | sudo tee /etc/someFile`.

Comment: Why would you be "forced" to use `sudo tee`? That just makes the file owned by root and creates a problem where there was none. What does your program actually do? We can't answer this because you 1) don't tell us what the real problem is, what the program is doing; 2) You say `chmod xxx` but don't give us the real `xxx` you used. It sounds like you just want `rm -f` but I can't understand the question well enough to be sure.

Comment: You shouldn't really be writing in `/etc` unless you understand the implications. Write to somewhere you have access and you can avoid the mess with `tee`

Comment: @roaima It was an example of what the program's capabilities are... A practical example would be writing to `/etc/apt/sources.list` on a Debian/Debian based distro,.. Another good example is editing the `environment` file, the `bashrc`, or your X11 configs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `tee`, when passed a non-existing file as parameter, will create that file before writing the output to it. By prepending that command with `sudo`, you are asking your shell to run the `tee` command as `root`. The consequence is that the file created by `tee` is owned by the user starting the command: `root`, and is therefore read-only for other users. You can see this by yourself if you run `ls -l` and look at the `user` and `group` columns.

```
$ rm -f writeProtectedFile # Removing the file in case it already exists
$ echo $text | sudo tee writeProtectedFile
yourtext
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9 22.07.2015 14:26 writeProtectedFile
```

There are several options to overcome this:

- Create the file as a standard user before asking `tee` to write to it. `tee` will then either truncate or simply `--append` to it, without changing its ownership:

  ```
  $ touch writeProtectedFile # creates the file as standard user
  $ echo $text | sudo tee writeProtectedFile
  $ rm writeProtectedFile
  ```
- Change the ownership of the file before trying to delete it:

  ```
  $ echo $text | sudo tee writeProtectedFile
  $ sudo chown $(whoami) writeProtectedFile # `whoami` returns the current user name
  $ rm writeProtectedFile
  ```
- Tell `rm` to ignore the fact that the file is write-protected, using `-f, --force`:

  ```
  $ echo $text | sudo tee writeProtectedFile
  $ rm --force writeProtectedFile
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If the file you are creating is in `/etc`, you won't be allowed to remove it anyway. That is to say, if we are regular user, and we do this:

```
$ sudo touch /etc/foobar
$ rm /etc/foobar
```

The `touch` will work, but the `rm` will fail, because we do not have write permissions to the `/etc` directory.

At the operating system kernel level, write permissions on a file are irrelevant in regard to its deletion (or rename/move). The prompt about deleting a write-protected file is just an application-level feature cooked into the `rm` program. When you say `y` to the prompt, `rm` makes a call to the operating system (most likely the `unlink` function) to blow the file away, without changing its permissions first. (Note that since you don't own the file, changing its permissions is not even permitted!)

However, anything that changes the contents of a directory (like adding or removing a file) requires write permissions for the directory.

So, in summary, the thing to do here is:

```
$ sudo rm -f /etc/foobar
```

The `sudo` to be root, so as to have the needed write access to `/etc` and the `-f` to suppress the prompt out of `rm`.

Answer (score -1):

You say that your goal is the equivalent of

```
sudo echo "whatever" >> /etc/someFile
```

but with the redirection `>>` also given root privileges. Have you considered this alternative

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'whatever' >> /etc/someFile"
```

I have used double quotes around the expression so that shell variables (if any) are interpolated before `sudo sh` is called, rather than trying to delay the evaluation for the `sh`. This is mainly because `sudo` pares down the environment so some variables may not exist and others may have been reset. Fo example `$$` will present the caller's pid rather than that of the `sh`.

Comment: This is not an answer; it's just a different way of getting the same problem — the newly created file will still be owned by "root".

Comment: @Scott I don't see anywhere in the question a requirement that specifies ownership. Having just re-read the question and my answer I'm puzzled why you say it's not a (valid) answer

Comment: (1) Your answer seems to provide a different way of doing what the OP is already doing.  The OP didn’t ask for a different way of doing what he/she is already doing; the question asks how to solve a problem (which your answer doesn’t address).  (2) The question says (paraphrased) «When I use `echo $text | sudo tee $file` … as a side effect, when it makes (creates) a file, it also write protects regular files, … and when I use `rm` on the file, it prompts me `remove write-protected regular file …?`»  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  While the question is unclear (e.g., there’s no `ls -l` output), [Emeric has come up with a plausible explanation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217606/23408) — when the user creates a file with `sudo tee`, it is owned by root, and so he can’t subsequently modify it without using `sudo` again (or, at least, needing to answer the prompt from `rm`).  Hence my comment — if the user’s script uses your command to append to a file that doesn’t exist, it will be created owned by root, and the user won’t have write access to it.

Comment: @scott appending or overwriting a file that already exists does not change its permissions or ownership. (Perhaps you'd like to try my suggestion before claiming it won't work?)

Comment: No, I’m not arguing with that, but there are millions of commands that “work” but aren’t answers to the question; your answer falls into that category.  The question asks, “How can I un-write protect file made by tee?”; your answer doesn’t address the issue of file protections.  The question says, «I want to use commands A and B, but they don’t work, so I use C and D (respectively) instead.  But command C causes a problem.  How can I fix this problem with command C?»  And you say «Command F is another surrogate for command B,» without offering any advantage command F has over command D.

Comment: @Scott the first sentence of the question itself states, « _I want to ensure that it [my program] works on both write protected files and un-write protected files_ ». I have answered that requirement.